# SFDX commands to export and import related objects

Tags: salesforcedx, data, data-export, scratch-org

I have read everything in the documentation on how to export and import data between orgs using SFDX commands.

But I am struggling to write a script which serializes all related objects. Here is the ER-diagram

[image]

The relationships between those objects are not serialized correctly. No matter how I structure my initial queries, if I start exporting child or parent objects with or without subqueries.

**extract-data.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Name, lkp_Account__c, lkp_Case__c, lkp_Contact__c, lkp_Lead__c, lkp_Opportunity__c FROM Note__c"

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Note__r) FROM Account"

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Note__r) FROM Contact"

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Note__r) FROM Case"

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Note__r) FROM Lead"

sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Note__r) FROM Opportunity"
```

The [trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/tree/develop/data) repo seems to do it right but doesn't share its creation script.

Comment: Using force:data:tree:export, I presume?

Comment: Yes, export and import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that all your objects *are* related together. You can use parent queries in your SOQL:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir data --plan --query \
    "SELECT Name, lkp_Account__r.Name, lkp_Case__r.Subject, lkp_Contact__r.FirstName, lkp_Contact__r.LastName, lkp_Lead__r.FirstName, lkp_Lead__r.LastName, lkp_Opportunity__r.AccountId, lkp_Opportunity__r.StageName, lkp_Opportunity__r.CloseDate, lkp_Opportunity__r.Amount FROM Note__c"
```

Add any additional fields as appropriate.

If you had a more complicated setup that actually involved multiple queries, you'd have to manually stitch the files together by editing the "refs" in each of the JSON files, and make sure your plan file imports records in the appropriate order. Circular dependencies are not allowed as far as I can tell.

In those cases, you'd have to use the Bulk API import option to import by External ID values.